# Can Struts2 Checkbox be created with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, struts2

I want to know if struts2 `<s:checkbox>` be created under bootstrap form.  Please take a look at my jsp code. Checkbox doesn't come up. It shows up if I create a checkbox the normal way like input type="checkbox" but I have to create it using struts2 tags to be able to process the form using struts2 action.

jsp

```
<s:form action="exportDocumentExport" namespace="/esignmain/documentExport" name="documentExportForm" theme="bootstrap" cssClass="form-vertical">
        <%-- Message --%>
        <div class="message">
            <s:if test="message != null">
                <strong style="color:#7F0E11"><s:property value="message"/></strong>
            </s:if>
        </div>

    <s:if test="message == null">
    <div class="scrollView11">
        <table id="eSignUsers" class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><s:text name="S.NO"/></th>
                    <th><s:text name="Document identifier"/></th>
                    <th><s:text name="Name"/></th>
                    <th><s:text name="Description"/></th>
                    <th><s:text name="Active"/></th>            
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr>
                <s:iterator value="documentList" status="status">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>    
                            <td><s:property value="#status.count" /></td>
                            <td><s:property value="identifier" /></td> 
                            <td><s:property value="name" /></td>
                            <td><s:property value="description" /></td>
                            <td><s:property value="active" /></td>
                            <td><s:checkbox name="checked" fieldValue="%{id}" value="false"/></td>  
                        </tr>       
                    </tbody>                                
                </s:iterator>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <tr>
                        <h5>Showing <span id="totalRows" class="label label-success"></span> total records</h5>
                        <s:submit key="Export Document" value="Export Document" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" name="Export_Document" theme="simple" onclick="return evalGroup()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-export"></span> Export</s:submit>
                    </tr>   
                </table>
            </tr> 
    </table>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Post the code to show how did you bootstrap a checkbox

Comment: Please, elaborate

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: The S2 tags just produce markup; there's no reason you *have* to use them other than convenience and some minimal framework integration. You might be interested in https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to create a [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#checkboxes-and-radios)-styled checkbox using `<s:checkbox>`

Try this:

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <s:checkbox name="..."/>
    Your label here
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: What I meant was that I don't see any checkbox because of s:checkbox tag.

Comment: @fustaki, it worked. Actually it looks like there has to be a label property whether or not we need it. The checkbox showed up properly as soon I added the label.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the Struts2 Bootstrap plugin project.  It handles all the bootstrap markup in the provided jsp tempaltes

http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-bootstrap-showcase/index.action